# Ursina Engine Error

Tags: python, ursina

не работает код, выдает ошибку, код:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.input_handler import update


class Game(Ursina):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        window.color = color.black
        window.fullscreen_size = 1920, 1080
        window.fullscreen = True
        Light(type='ambient' , color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)) 
        Light(type='directional', color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), direction=(1, 1, 1))

    def new_game(self):
        pass

    def input(self, key):
        super().input(key)

    def update(self):
        pass


if __name__ =='__main__':
    game = Game()
    update = game.update
    game.run()
```

ошибка такая:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PC-TV\Desktop\Snakee 3D\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ursina.input_handler import update
ImportError: cannot import name 'update' from 'ursina.input_handler' (C:\Users\PC-TV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\ursina\input_handler.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых в этом модуле действительно нет такой функции. Во-вторых вы никак не используете в своём коде ни `input_handler` ни этот `update`, даже если бы он и был в библиотеке. Так что можете эту строчку где выходит ошибка просто удалить/закомментировать.

```
from ursina import *
# from ursina.input_handler import update
```